# Какие основные проблемы возникают при вмешательстве в код уже созданных программ?

Tags: reverse-engineering

Всем большое спасибо за столь обширные ответы. Это просто был вопрос из лабы по системному программированию.

Comment: Сменил метку на более нейтральную:)

"Вмешательство в код уже созданных программ" это не всегда "крэкинг".

Comment: Проблемы с законом? :-)

Comment: @Чад, вы Капитан Очевидность. Рассмотрим сферический в вакууме вариант, когда автор программы не хочет делиться исходниками, но ничего не имеет против сторонних модов, конечно же с сохранением ссылки на оригинальную программу.

Comment: @insolor, Обычно в таких случаях автор программы реализует систему плагинов для своего творения.

Comment: @Чад, случаи бывают разные, не только "обычные" :)

Comment: Не всегда! У меня есть программа, которой пользуются многие знакомые и друзья. Но я не добавляю Plugin Engine потому что это требует времени! Хорошо подумать, чтобы было удобно пользоваться и поддерживать. А у меня есть и другие , более важные задачи чем система плагинов для этой программы. И казалось бы открой на Open-Source, но у меня там очень много кода, который использую в коммерческих проектах.

Comment: @sys_dev, вроде бы BSD лицензия не требует открытия всего кода целиком. "Закрытые" куски можно поставлять в виде бинарников (объектных файлов или библиотек), остальное в виде исходников.

Comment: @insolor:
А redesign программы кто будет делать? ;) Написание хороших оберток тоже работа и следовательно трата времени. Обертки абы как ведут к тому, что появляется гуан-код и следовательно более медленному добавлению фич и более частому появлению багов, чем у более читабельного кода.

Comment: @sys_dev, Да, а правка бинарного кода это конечно полностью безопасный процесс и менее трудоёмкий чем сделать систему плагинов? Если цель только в том чтобы добавить пару фич?

Comment: @Чад:
А никто и не говорит что что-то безопаснее чем другое. Я лишь говорю о том, что когда мне фича не нужна и я в ней никогда не нуждался, то я не буду тратить свое время на ее добавление! А если вдруг это кому-то надо, то бога ради делай что хочешь мне глубоко фиалетово, но в этом случае риск по работоспособности приложения человек берет на себя и обращаться ко мне со словами : "У тебя тут... падает" не имеет права!

Comment: @sys_dev, а если человек встраивает туда вредоносный код? И под вашем брендом будет распространять Ваше приложение Вам тоже фиолетово? Я не спорю что если человек это делает исключительно для "частного домашнего просмотра", но обычно это не так.

Comment: @Чад:
Вам разве не известно, что перед выкладыванием программ настоятельно рекомендуется поставлять также и файл Checksum.txt , вот пример подобного файла: ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/amd64/amd64/ISO-IMAGES/9.2/CHECKSUM.MD5 благодаря такой информации пользователь может сверить скачанное с тем что у него. А уж что дальше в мире происходит, то уже одному богу известно и если на каждый чих визжать "А вдруг...?", то можно сума сойти. Да и я всегда извещаю ребят: "Тщательно смотрите то что Вы делаете, программа расчитана на программистов, т.е. людей с головою!".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[@Jeremen1](/users/8698/jeremen1): Вы как-то слишком обширный вопрос задали! Проблем может быть очень много, примеры:

- Ошибка доступа;
- Нарушение конвенции вызова;
- Неправильно скорректировали стек;
- Случайно изменили байты машинного кода;
- Вышли за пределы подправляемых данных и изменили то что не должны были менять.

и др.

Answer (score 5):

Как правило, зависит от "этичности" разработчиков и от внедренной ими системы безопасности.
Взять, к примеру, небезызвестный Skype. В нем все настолько запутано, что даже самых матерых реверсов он, порой, выводит из себя. В его тщательно сокрытом коде много неразгаданных тайн, касающихся VoIP телефонии, обхода брэндмауэров и нестандартного использования протоколов TCP/IP && UDP. Часто, любое вмешательство в такой код приводит к отказу приложения функционировать( вылетам ).

Недавно я ломал систему защиты игры GTA IV. Мне удалось приблизиться очень близко к сути( я пытался сделать так, чтобы загрузка игры была возможна без диска ). Но в самом конце пути меня ожидала неприятная неожиданность - как оказалось, код игры исполнялся в отведенном( обособленном ) адресном пространстве( как в системах виртуализации ), куда дублировался слепок памяти, находящийся вне виртуальной среды. Следовательно, любое изменение байта в ASM-коде приводило к вылету( срабатывала система защиты ). Так что до сути я так и не докопался..

Короче говоря, может произойти все, что угодно - от простого вылета до BSOD( если речь о Windows-системах ). Последнее, кстати, может произойти при копании в системных программах.

Answer (score 4):

Если интересно, почти два года применяю реверс инженеринг в мирных целях, а именно разрабатываю русификатор для одной игры (в качестве хобби).

Общие проблемы: побочные эффекты от внесенных измений - вылеты, зависания и т.д. Причина локализуется и вносятся соответствующие поправки в русификатор.

Из специфических проблем - обычно длина строки передается в конструктор строки явно (через регистр или в стеке). Если она указывается как непосредственное значение (число), то особых проблем ее исправление не вызывает (хотя бывают случаи, когда одно и то же значение длины используется для нескольких строк). В других случаях где-то выше по коду в один из регистров записывается значение, а при вызове конструктора это значение передается в качестве длины. Сейчас пробую вшивать в код конструктора что-то вроде strlen, чтобы длина определялась автоматически, но пока что это вызывает те самые "общие проблемы" :)